# Difference between a "plain" terms query and a terms query using a filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to understand what the difference is between:

- a "plain" elasticsearch query that is going to match a **terms** query and return a certain number of hits.
- and a **filtered** query (therefore using a **filter**) that is going to return the same number of hits.

Here is the **terms** query:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "childcareTypes": [
            "SOLE_CHARGE",
            "OUT_OF_SCHOOL",
            "BABY_SITTING"
         ],
         "minimum_match": 3
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the **filtered** version:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SOLE_CHARGE",
                  "OUT_OF_SCHOOL",
                  "BABY_SITTING"
               ],
               "execution": "and"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Both return a total hits of 8000 (against my index).

Here is the result from the "plain" terms query:

```
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 8000,
      "max_score": 5.134171,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bignibou",
            "_type": "advertisement",
            "_id": "AUs2T2lt3L5LNr7nkot2",
            "_score": 5.134171,
            "_source": {
               "childcareWorkerType": "AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE",
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SOLE_CHARGE",
                  "OUT_OF_SCHOOL",
                  "BABY_SITTING"
               ],
               "address": {
                  "latitude": 48.8532558,
                  "longitude": 2.36584
               },
               "giveBath": "EMPTY"
            }
         },
         ...
```

Here is the result from the "filtered" query:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 8000,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bignibou",
            "_type": "advertisement",
            "_id": "AUs2T2lt3L5LNr7nkot2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "childcareWorkerType": "AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE",
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SOLE_CHARGE",
                  "OUT_OF_SCHOOL",
                  "BABY_SITTING"
               ],
               "address": {
                  "latitude": 48.8532558,
                  "longitude": 2.36584
               },
               "giveBath": "EMPTY"
            }
         },
         ....
```

**Then what are the differences between the two?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the differences between **queries** and **filters** ([more information here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html#_queries_and_filters)).

In your case, unlike `terms` query, `terms` filter :

- is **cached**
- **doesn't compute the score** : all matching documents have the same `_score` of 1 (look at your results)

Consequently, the biggest difference is that the `filtered` query will be faster than a 'plain' `terms` query.